compare two dateTime Objects in PHP (Symfony 7)

    #[Route('/show/{id}', name: 'app_warning_show', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function show(Warning $warning): Response
    {
        $time = new \DateTime('now');
        $this->checkAccess(['ROLE_WHITELIST','ROLE_FRACTION','ROLE_SUPPORT','ROLE_ADMIN']);
        return $this->render('warning/show.html.twig', [
            'warning' => $warning,
            'expired' => $time > $warning->getEnd(),
        ]);
    }

Created Datetime in DB -> 2024-04-06 12:13:00
Duration are 10h
    public function getEnd() {
        return date('d.m.Y - H:i:s', ($this->getCreated()->getTimestamp() + ($this->getFrakBanDuration() * 3600)));
    }

Try 1: (getCreated()) 2024-04-06 12:13:00 + (getFrakBanDuration()) 10h = (getEnd()) 06.04.2024 - 22:13:00
Try 2: (getCreated()) 2024-04-06 12:13:00 + (getFrakBanDuration()) 23h = (getEnd()) 07.04.2024 - 11:13:00
Try 3: (getCreated()) 2024-04-06 12:13:00 + (getFrakBanDuration()) 100h = (getEnd()) 10.04.2024 - 16:13:00
$time = new DateTime('now');
$time > $warning->getEnd() IT IS ALWAYS TRUE?????
The condition 'expired' => $time > $warning->getEnd(), ist ALWAYS True.
I compared the Timestamp and the Object in all directions and options and chanced the duration from 10 to 100. So the new End ist 10.04.2024 the old was 06.04.2024. How the f*** is it possible?? I dont get it.

$time is \DateTime and getEnd() is string. You are comparing \DateTime with string. Operands should be same type when we do compare.

Your code can be summarised as:
var_dump(new \DateTime() > '2024-04-06 12:13:00');

which indeed produces bool(true). This is documented at Comparison with Various Types:

Type of Operand 1: object
Type of Operand 2: anything
Result: object is always greater

It does not make sense to use text for date calculations, more than it does for numbers:
var_dump('one' > 'eleven'); // bool(true)

If you are using date objects, stick to that. There's no need to convert to text or Unix time, nor to build your own date calculation logic:
public function getEnd(): \DateTime
{
    return (clone $this->getCreated())->modify('+' . $this->getFrakBanDuration() . 'hours');
}

(Note I'm cloning to $this->getCreated() to avoid side effects, this is not really part of the calculations).

I'm sorry, my fault..
Damn you're right. It was very late yesterday and I didn't understand it anymore. Of course it makes sense that I can't compare strings with each other.
After seeing your examples, I understood it. I don't have to compare the times as text but as a timestamp, i.e. int vs. int.
It was further difficult because I had to compare it in TWIG.
Solution:
{% set currDate = date() %}
{% if warning.expireDate and warning.expireDate.timeStamp > currDate.timeStamp %}

Thanks for shortening the code.
